# Where function on list with multiple conditions returns errors

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a list based on a few criteria and the .Where() function gives me an error in 2 parts of the same method.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(champs))
            {
                data = dal.GetVueTache().Where(t =>
                    t.ProjetDescription64.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower()) 
                    // *This Line || t.ProjetDescription256.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower())
                    || t.Description256.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower())
                    ||t.ResponsableNomCourt.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower())
                    || t.PrioriteDesc.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower())
                    ).ToList();
            }
```

If I use any of the previous conditions except the one on the nullable field alone I get a perfectly filtered list on that criteria, if I add an OR "||" then I get a *System.NullReferenceException* on the first criteria.

---

I also have a similar issue in another part of the same method

```
else
                {   
                    data = dal.GetVueTache().Where(t => 
                        t.GetType().GetProperty(champs).GetValue(t).ToString().ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower())
                        ).ToList();
                }
```

This one filters my list based on the criteria "filtre" on the property "champs". It works on every property but the second one, which is a nullable one. I understand that this is where the issue comes from, but I can't find a way to test if the property is null before evaluating it and work around this from inside the .Where() Method.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!!

---

**Edit :**

Thanks to **Ivan Stoev** for his solution!

The correct syntax for testing the null value in the first case is:

```
|| (t.ProjetDescription256 != null && t.ProjetDescription256.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower()))
```

In the second case:

```
(t.GetType().GetProperty(champs).GetValue(t) != null && t.GetType().GetProperty(champs).GetValue(t).ToString().ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower()))
```

Comment: are you sure you even need to use ToLower?

Comment: I use it to make the search parameters case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a `null` check either the old way:

```
|| (t.ProjetDescription256 != null && t.ProjetDescription256.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower()))
```

or the C# 6 way (utilizing the [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)):

```
|| t.ProjetDescription256?.ToLower().Contains(filtre.ToLower()) == true
```

Btw, you can greatly simplify similar checks and avoid such errors by writing a simple custom extension methods like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string target)
    {
        return source == null ? target == null : target != null && source.IndexOf(target, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}
```

so your snippet becomes simply:

```
data = dal.GetVueTache().Where(
    t => t.ProjetDescription64.ContainsIgnoreCase(filtre) 
    || t.ProjetDescription256.ContainsIgnoreCase(filtre)
    || t.Description256.ContainsIgnoreCase(filtre)
    || t.ResponsableNomCourt.ContainsIgnoreCase(filtre)
    || t.PrioriteDesc.ContainsIgnoreCase(filtre)
).ToList();
```

Comment: The second one doesn't seem to work in the context of a .Where() function, but the first one did!

Thank you!!

Comment: As soon as this is LINQ to Objects, both should work. If LINQ to Entities, your original query should not raise NRE.